# Looking for advice on handling generic SOAP responses

Tags: wpf, xml, serialization, soap, deserialization

I am working on the GUI (WPF) of a new app that will be sending various SOAP requests and getting back SOAP responses that will be formed using a generic format.  Here is a sample response:

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <TheResponse>
        <MetaData>
          <DataSchema>
            <ColumnSchema type="decimal" ref="c0" name="min" />
            <ColumnSchema type="decimal" ref="c1" name="max" />
          </DataSchema>
        </MetaData>
        <Data>
          <Item>
            <c0>0</c0>
            <c1>1</c1>
          </Item>
        </Data>
    </TheResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

So as you can see, the SOAP response will define the meta data and then the actual data.  I need to create different objects depending on the request/response.  In this example, the object would have two properties, Min and Max, whose values are 0 and 1 respectively.

If I have the classes defined for the objects I know I would need, for example:

```
class MyClass
{
   public decimal Min {get; set;}
   public decimal Max {get; set;}
}
```

how would I go about deserializing the SOAP response to create the appropriate object?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend starting with defining a XML schema for you Soap message using [XSD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Once you have a schema you can generate a class using the following:

From the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt, run
Xsd.exe schema.xsd /classes /language:[CS | VB].

Now that you have a class you can use [XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx) to convert from an object to XML and from XML to an object using the class generated via XSD.

These steps remove the need to manually write code to examine/parse the XML.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Using the method you outlined, would the values in my example for <c0> and <c1> correctly populate the Min/Max properties?  Would it know to link the values in the <Data> section to the property names in the <DataSchema> section?

Comment: Based your example I see your metadata (DataSchema) getting defined as an XSD schema that you use to generate a class that is used to transmit the data via Serialization in your Soap message.  This allows the value for c0 and c1 to get loaded into the object.

The purpose of my answer is to try and guide you to avoid writing code that parses and XML and converts the XML to an object.